# it there any way to convert 3D numpy array to 2D

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got a 3d NumPy array:

```
array([[[ 12.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 15.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 13.,  0.,  0.]],

   [[ 12.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 11.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 13.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Is there any way to convert to a 2d and only get

```
[12., 15., 13.]
[12., 11., 13.]
```

Comment: You want `x[..., 0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = np.array(
  [[[ 12.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 15.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 13.,  0.,  0.]],

   [[ 12.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 11.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 13.,  0.,  0.]]]
)

x_2d = x[:, :, 0]

>> x_2d
>> array([[12., 15., 13.],
          [12., 11., 13.]])
```